# How would i reference a frame in flash using XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, flash, actionscript

I have a Flash movie that reads information from a mysql database, using PHP to create XML.
I want to use the outside dynamic content to reference a different frames within the flash movie.

For example, wherever dataY is displayed on click link to frame Y / wherever dataX is displayed on click link to frame X

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "outside dynamic content"? Is this the XML which defines dataY and dataX?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExternalInterface.addCallBack](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29) for this. Basically you expose a method from within the swf that your javascript code can call.